# Using Edittext for Countdown timer

Tags: java, android-studio, countdowntimer

i have find a code for countdown timer but the value is 10 sec. i want it to get the values from Edittext this is the code

```
private static final long TIMER_LENGHT = 10; // Ten seconds
    private long mTimeToGo;
    private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;
    private TimerState mState;
```

i did that

```
Edittext1 et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Edittext1);
String strInput = et1.getText().toString();
private static final long TIMER_LENGHT = et1; 
private long mTimeToGo;
private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;
private TimerState mState;
```

but it did not work what can i do to make it work *[this is the Full code i'm using](https://github.com/phthhieu/Android-Timer/tree/master/AndroidTimerSample)

Comment: **First off**, you didint post the code that makes the `Countdowntimer` run (Method called every tick), **Second**, the timer length should be in Milliseconds. Also, what did you ***try*** to make it work?

Comment: the full code is here https://github.com/phthhieu/Android-Timer/tree/master/AndroidTimerSample but i was wondering if i can make it work wihen i add edit text or not

Comment: Read this on Countdowntimer's:
  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer

Comment: Try to post the code instead of putting a link to it. Also, the link is too confusing, cant find the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't this :

```
private static final long TIMER_LENGHT = et1;
```

be:

```
private static final long TIMER_LENGHT = Long.parseLong(strInput);
```

EDIT:

First change your TIMER_LENGTH TO:

```
  private long TIMER_LENGHT = 0;
```

We'll start it off as 0 and later when we click the button we change it:

```
@OnClick(R.id.main_timer_button)
    public void onButtonClicked() {
        if  (mState == TimerState.STOPPED) {
            mPreferences.setStartedTime(getNow());
            EditText et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);
            String strInput = et1.getText().toString().trim();
            TIMER_LENGHT = Long.parseLong(strInput);
            startTimer();
            mState = TimerState.RUNNING;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That is an error in his code but, this dosent answer the question. Comment that instead.

Comment: The question was "but it did not work what can i do to make it work". I spotted this error in the code, so I believe it does answer the OP question

Comment: Oh wait, his code is in "this website" sorry that confused me. I thought he didint even make the countdowntimer

Comment: i try it but i get this error "Non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context" i made TIMER_LENGHT not static but the app crash when i try to open it